# Two questions on Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: .net, tfs

I've some questions about TFS 2010.

1) Do you know an easy way to move a work item from a project to another one using Team Explorer?

2) Can TFS's reporting portal show work items of all projects in some collection in the same listing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, you can't.  Each project has separate set of work item type definitions, so moving from one project to another isn't supported.

2) Yes, you can - just tell your report not to filter by project.

Comment: I see, I was looking for a confirmation. Thank you. Anyway, now talking about 2nd question, I found that using Team Explorer, if you export a list of work items not filtered by project TFS gives you an error concerning that you can't export to excel work items from different projects. I assume that this is a Team Explorer limitation, isn't it? Thank you.

Comment: Excel exports only work from a single team project - again a limitation of the differing templates between projects, I think.